# Mark name of location on map?

Tags: android, maps, location

In my Android app I want to mark on map a location (I know the address of location). When I mark it on map, I want to display the name of location,too. How can I do that?

I have this: OverlayItem(p ,"Kaufland", "Magic Kingdom"),but on map appear only the point,without the name.

Here is my code:

```
package com.ShoppingList.Shops;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.ShoppingList.R;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class ShowMap extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showmap);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);

        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
        marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
        marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

        InterestingLocations funPlaces = new InterestingLocations(marker);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(funPlaces);
        GeoPoint pt = funPlaces.getCenter(); // get the first-ranked point
        mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(15);

    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
    return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
    }
    class InterestingLocations extends ItemizedOverlay {
        private List locations = new ArrayList();
        private Drawable marker;
        String adresa;
        public InterestingLocations(Drawable marker)
        {
        super(marker);
        this.marker=marker;
        // create locations of interest
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        adresa = bundle.getString("adress");

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(ShowMap.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
        List addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(adresa, 5);
            String add = "";
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                locations.add(new OverlayItem(p ,"Kaufland", "Magic Kingdom"));

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        populate();
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    boundCenterBottom(marker);
    }
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return locations.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
    return locations.size();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe there's no easier way but it doesn't look like there is. Here is one method:
http://binwaheed.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-display-title-on-marker-in.html

Also I highly recommend using anti-aliasing unless you want ugly text:

```
TextPaint paintText = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a Toast to display the text indicated by the marker.  Here's how I solved it for a demo project:

-- begin Location.java --

```
package com.cb2enterprises.geocode;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class Location 
{
public GeoPoint Point;
public String Title;
public String Snippet;

public Location(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet)
{
    Point = point;
    Title = title;
    Snippet = snippet;
}
}
```

-- end --

-- begin PushpinOverlay.java --

```
package com.cb2enterprises.geocode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PushpinOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> 
{
    private List<Location> mItems;
    Context mContext = null;

    public PushpinOverlay(Context context, Drawable marker)
{
    super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    mContext = context;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<Location> items)
{
    mItems = items;
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) 
{
    return new OverlayItem(mItems.get(i).Point, mItems.get(i).Title, mItems.get(i).Snippet);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int i)
{
    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(mContext, mItems.get(i).Title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg.getXOffset() / 2, msg.getYOffset() / 2);
    msg.show();
    return true;
}
}
```

-- end --

-- begin GeoCodeDemoActivity.java --

```
package com.cb2enterprises.geocode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;

public class GeoCodeDemoActivity extends MapActivity 
{
    Geocoder geocoder = null;
    MapView mapView = null;
    ProgressDialog progDialog = null;
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    MyLocationOverlay curLocOverlay = null;
    ArrayList<Location> locations = null;
    PushpinOverlay pushpin = null;

@Override
protected boolean isLocationDisplayed()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.geoMap);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
    pushpin = new PushpinOverlay(this, icon);

    // put the current location as hockey puck
    curLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    curLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() 
    { 
        public void run()
        {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(curLocOverlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
    mapView.getOverlays().add(curLocOverlay);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(12);

    Button geoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.geocodeBtn);

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    geoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            EditText loc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location);
            String locationName = loc.getText().toString();
            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GeoCodeDemoActivity.this, "Processing", 
                         "Finding location", true, false);
            findLocation(locationName);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    curLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    curLocOverlay.disableMyLocation();
}

private void findLocation(final String locationName)
{
    Thread thrd = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                //do background work
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);
                //send message to handler to process results
                uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thrd.start();
}

//ui thread callback handler
private Handler uiCallback = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        progDialog.dismiss();
        if(addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0)
        {
            int lat = (int)(addressList.get(0).getLatitude()*1E6);
            int lng = (int)(addressList.get(0).getLongitude()*1E6);
            GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            locations.add(new Location(pt, addressList.get(0).getFeatureName(), addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0)));
            pushpin.setItems(locations);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(pushpin);
            mapView.getController().setCenter(locations.get(locations.size()-1).Point);
            mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
        }
        else
        {
            Dialog foundNothingDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(GeoCodeDemoActivity.this)
                                     .setIcon(0)
                                     .setTitle("Failed to find location")
                                     .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                                     .setMessage("Location not found...")
                                     .create();
            foundNothingDlg.show();
        }
    }
};
}
```